# Regularly update file/folder structure in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a folder called "masterData"; this folder has approximately 500GB of data, 100k files, 500 folders.

I would like to load the list of all the file name and the location into SQL Server.

I can do this using SSIS. But I am wondering if there are other more efficient way out there, instead of having the job run for 10 hours/day checking if the filename exists in the table.

I wonder if there is a way to set a pointer/marker somehow, so every new filename will be added into the table.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) with associated event handlers that update your tables appropriately.